# Rust accessing Option from mutex

Tags: concurrency, rust, mutex

I am having trouble understanding how to modify Option inside a Mutex.

When there's no Option, it works fine

```
let mut my_int = Arc::new(Mutex::new(5));

let my_int_clone = Arc::clone(&my_int);

thread::spawn(move || {
  let mut my_int = my_int_clone.lock().unwrap();
  *my_int += 1;
}).join();

let my_int_clone_print = Arc::clone(&my_int);
println!("Value: {}", my_int_clone_print.lock().unwrap());
```

However, when I wrap the value in `Some`, I had to manually use `ref mut` and such (I found it from [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/accessing-option-from-mutex/8370)) because the `lock().unwrap()` returns `MutexGuard`, not the `Option` itself.

```
let mut my_int = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(5)));

let my_int_clone = Arc::clone(&my_int);

thread::spawn(move || {
  let mut my_int = my_int_clone.lock().unwrap();

  match *my_int {
    Some(ref mut val) => {
      *val += 1;
    },
    None => {
      println!("Value is None. Doing nothing..");
    }
  }

}).join();

let my_int_clone_print = Arc::clone(&my_int);
println!("Value: {}", my_int_clone_print.lock().unwrap());
```

Any idea which Rust concept causes this? And also are there any more data types besides `Option` which returns `MutexGuard` and not its original value?

Comment: Please note that on StackOverflow, when the question is resolved, the person who asked it is expected to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709) the most deserving answer. This removes the question from the list of unanswered questions, provides future visitors with a hint as to which answer is the best (in the eyes of the original poster), and rewards the volunteer who wrote it with a token reputation award. If the answers do not address your question, you might want to edit the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, `Mutex::lock` [returns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) `Result<MutexGuard, ..>` in both cases. Though, this type has interesting trait implementation: [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html). These allow explicit dereference via `*` operator. Consider this example with the explicit types:

```rust
let mutex = Mutex::new(1i32);
let mut guard: MutexGuard<'_, i32> = mutex.lock().unwrap();

// This dereferences to &mut i32 
// because assignment operator works with &mut self.
*guard = 2;

// Nevertheless, for an explicit borrowing you need &mut
// because otherwise it would be moved from the guard.
let inner: &mut i32 = &mut *guard;
```

And, of course, you can use `Option` similarly:

```rust
let mutex = Mutex::new(Some(1i32));
let mut guard: MutexGuard<'_, Option<i32>> = mutex.lock().unwrap();

// Directly change inner value
*guard = Some(2);

// or use in match, notice &mut borrowing
match &mut *guard {
    Some(x) => *x += 1,
    None => {},
}
```

Notice, the last match example is exactly the same as yours but uses a slightly different syntax. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=788c8ae88f6e97ad7988761151a039ac).

Answer (score 4):

> there any more data types besides `Option` which returns `MutexGuard` and not its original value?

`MutexGuard` can't return the original value because moving the value would invalidate the mutex. Instead, it's a wrapper that provides a mutable *reference* to the original value.

That's in no way specific to `Option`, a `MutexGuard` is what `Mutex::lock` always returns. For example, this code:

```
let m = Mutex::<bool>::new(false);
let () = m.lock().unwrap();
```

...will report that the type returned by `m.lock().unwrap()` is `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, bool>`.

`MutexGuard` gives out access to the data under the condition that the reference does not outlive the guard. `*my_int += 1` works because `MutexGuard` implements [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html), which tells the `*` operator what reference to work on. And the `*` operator works perfectly fine with `Option`; for example:

```
let m = Mutex::<Option<i32>>::new(Some(0));
let mut my_int = m.lock().unwrap();
*my_int = Some(100);
```

Matching an `*my_int` can be done without `ref mut`, but then `*my_int` will copy the option (which works as long as its contents are `Copy`) and modifying the value will have no effect on the option itself. This is again in no way specific to `MutexGuard`, it's how matching works. The `ref mut` is required to give you mutable access to the data inside the option.